# zeros in simple algebraic extenison

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field, splitting-field

Theorem: Let $f\in k[x]$ be irreducible. There exists a simple algebraic extension $K/k$ with $[K:k]=deg(f)$, such that $f$ has a zero in $K$.

Well, I read the following lecture notes about how to proof this theorem but I did not understand.

Proof:This is a formal, almost tautological construction. We will use f to construct the field. As $f$ is irreducible and $k[x]$ is a PID, we know that $K:=k[x]/<f>$ is field. Let $\pi:k[x]\rightarrow K$ be the canonical projection. $\pi|_{k}$ is surjective and the image is a subfield of $K$(which we identify with $k$). Thus $K/k$ is a field extension. We claim that $f$ has a zero in $K$, namely the class [x]: Write $f:=\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i$ with $a_i\in k$
.Then $$0=[f]=\sum_{i=0}^n[a_i][x^i]=\sum_{i=0}^na_i[x]^i=f([x])$$
Thus $[x]$ is a zero of $f$ in $k$, and $K=k([x])$.

Finally we determine $[K:k]$. By dividing $f$ by its leading coefficient we can assume that $f$ is monic. So $f$ is an irreducible monic polynomial with $f([x])=0$ that is $f$ is the minimal ploynomialof [x] over $k$. Thus $[K:k]=deg(f).$\

Here comes my question: I didnt understand how could one derive the equation in the middle of the proof. I am not sure if I understand the proof correctly: $[f]$ is the additive identity in $K$ and hence it is zero. And $[x]$ is the coset of $<f>$, namely $x+<f>$. But how could one factor out the $i$the power from the square bracket. I guess I didnt understand correctly what the notation means in the equation and also didnt see clearly how can one get the equation.

Thank you.

Comment: The other way to put this proof is to see that $\pi$ is a morphism of $k$-algebras and $[y]=\pi(y)$ for any $y \in k[x]$. If you want a way to construct $K$ without feeling too tautological, you can say that $K$ is the sub-$k$-algebra of $\mathcal{M}_n(k)$ generated by a matrix $A$ with minimal polynomial $f$. Then $k[x]/(f)$ is naturally isomorphic to $K$ and hence $K$ is a field, and $A \in K$ is a root of $f$.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still didnt understand. So what is class of [x] exactly?

Comment: I guess the equation can be derived by the axiom of ring homomorphism but I dont know what the notation means

Comment: $[x]$ is the image of $x \in k[x]$ under $\pi$. So it is, indeed, $x+(f)$.